# How to revert files with specific extension in svn through command line?

Tags: svn

In svn I am trying to revert all txt files recursively through command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of fiddling with command line I finally got it. The solution is as follow:

```
for /r %WorkingCopy% %%R in (*.txt) do if exist "%%R" (svn revert %%R)
```

Comment: Nice one! I use this to revert all the AssemblyInfo.cs files where i automatically changed the version numbers during my build process: `@for /r %WorkingCopy% %%R in (AssemblyInfo.cs) do @if exist "%%R" (svn revert %%R)`. Note the `@` signs to suppress the loads of console output.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you are asking:

```
svn revert *.txt
```

Comment: +1 for answer. Is there a way to do it recursively? It seems it can only apply to the current directory.

Comment: @odez213 I believe that the --recursive flag can do that.

Comment: @odez213 How's this: svn revert --recursive . *.txt

Comment: That didn't work. I finally got it to work and the answer is below.